# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'HRApiProject.Myapp'

Tags: python, django-models, django-rest-framework

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SO8Gq.png)While running add_data.py file, getting ModuleNotFoundError. I found that it is going to project level path as highlighted in the picture. Please help me in fixing this error.
"C:\Users\Manikanta\pythonProject\HRApiProject\HRApiProject" instead of this path "C:\Users\Manikanta\pythonProject\HRApiProject\Myapp"

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llpSW.png)Unable to import model name because of the above error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I created add_data.py file in management folder in application folder for adding file data to SQL.But it is unable to identify model as path is towards project level not application level